# Why are my buttons floating above the containing element? Is it bootstrap related?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I suspect it's bootstrap because if I don't include the bootstrap library, the code works fine. Any ideas on what it could be? I've included an example here to demonstrate the effect.

```css
#main-pane {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 180px;
  
}

#lower-bar {
  background-color: #0F6292;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  
}
.center-it {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class ="row" id = "main-pane">
    <div class= 'col-md-6 col-md-offset-1'>
      good dreams pupper
      </div>
</div>

<section id = 'lower-bar'>
  <div class = 'row'>
    <div class = 'col-md-12'>
      <div class = 'center-it'>
    
     <input type="button" id='btn-1' value ="Button 1">
     <input type="button" id='btn-2' value ="Button 2">
     <input type="button" id="btn-3" value="Button 3">
     <input type="button" id='btn-4' value ="Button 4">
     <input type="button" id="btn-5" value="Button 5">
     </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace: `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` in your .center-it css by `transform: translate(-50%,50%);`

```css
#main-pane {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 180px;
  
}

#lower-bar {
  background-color: #0F6292;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  
}
.center-it {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,50%);

  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class ="row" id = "main-pane">
    <div class= 'col-md-6 col-md-offset-1'>
      good dreams pupper
      </div>
</div>

<section id = 'lower-bar'>
  <div class = 'row'>
    <div class = 'col-md-12'>
      <div class = 'center-it'>
    
     <input type="button" id='btn-1' value ="Button 1">
     <input type="button" id='btn-2' value ="Button 2">
     <input type="button" id="btn-3" value="Button 3">
     <input type="button" id='btn-4' value ="Button 4">
     <input type="button" id="btn-5" value="Button 5">
     </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: why does that fix it?

Comment: because input are display in inline block by default: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ and the white-space: nowrap specified that the element white space are smallest

Comment: actually I just tried this (in the snippet and in my actual file). It doesn't fix the problem. It looks like it doesn't fix it in your snippet either.

Comment: it's working for me, what's your browser and the version?

Comment: chrome, v 51.0.2704.103

Comment: in case I didn't make it clear enough the buttons are supposed to go to the middle of the bottom blue bar

Comment: ah ok so still in your .center-it css replace the     transform: translate(-50%,-50%); by     transform: translate(-50%,50%);  i update my answer

Comment: EDIT: okay yeah that fixed it. Why did changing to transform: translate(-50%,100%) fix it?

Comment: actually depending where you want your button, but actually for center it it's more 50% than 100%, because the translate ( x : width , y: height ) so if your translate y is at -50% your are above the container